# Where should I load animation in my code(objective-c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the best place(method) to start animation in view controller in iOS app:

1. `viewDidLoad`
2. `viewWillAppear`
3. `viewDidAppear`

Thanks!

Comment: Do you think it make sense to animate UI unless it is visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad:` would be triggered for the first time when you load the view. In this method your animation won't run everytime you open the view.

`viewWillAppear:` is before loading the View. `viewDidAppear:` is after loading the View. These two methods will be called whenever you navigate from other view. If you want the animation to be started before appearing the view, go for `viewWillAppear:`. Otherwise goto `viewDidAppear:`. I use `viewDidAppear:` to make sure my users see the full animation.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is:
in the `viewDidApear` method.
the reason:
i want the animation to load after the view appeared and every time it appears if i will do it in the load method it won't happen after i will come back to the ViewController and if i put it in view will apear it may take few milisecs until the view loads so the animation won't start from the first frame so **it is the best to put it after the view alredy appeared.**

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad:` is generally the place to put view loading or refinement. If you put it in viewWillAppear, you may be needlessly reloading it if the user comes back to this screen and the animation was already loaded.

You may wish to start and stop the animation in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` if it reduces your memory or processing footprint.